# Can this code make your browser unstable?

Tags: html

The following code

```
<div id="w3stats"></div>
```

has been injected throughout one of my sites. My observation is with the code, Firefox becomes unstable, and then the computer becomes unstable. When removed the site seems stable.

Am I imagining things? Is this a real threat?

Comment: `<div id="w3stats"></div>` is the code i wanted to display

Comment: What have you done in trying to figure out what is causing the instability?

Comment: That alone wouldn't do anything, perhaps there is code elsewhere that was added? Javascript perhaps?

Comment: Probably it's best to google something like this when you see it than come here.  My answer was the first thing to come up in a Google search.  I just searched for the tag without the brackets.:  div id="w3stats"  and came up with the result immediately.

Comment: Mike, To answer your question, I brought up the site with the malware.  Firefox was unstable.  Removed malware, Firefox became stable.

Comment: David, I did google it.  Found the site below and still am puzzled. Also, the link below has javascript and is obviously malware.  My block above is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this, quickly.

http://techcosupport.com/press/malware-scripts-added-to-websites/

It's an indication that your site may have been infected with malware.

Comment: I'm confused because this is a code-less code insertion.  So nothing is running on the browser that I know of.  Pages with that code are blacklisted (where I'm not sure) and it's the latency of the blacklisting that I call 'unstable'.